# nounset option for bash in case of string concatenation

Tags: bash

Let's take a snippet:

```bsh
set -o nounset

var="${var}something"
echo $var
```

It fails with error:

```bsh
unset.sh: line 3: var: unbound variable
```

However when I use `+=` operator

```
set -o nounset

var+=something
echo $var
```

it runs without an error and prints:

```
something
```

For me such behaviour seems a little bit unexpected. 
Is it ok? 
Should `var+=something` and `var=${var}something` behave similarly or it is ok that they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thing to note here is that the `bash` shell limits the scope of the POSIX `nounset` option to *only* explicit expansions of variables.

That is, the `nounset` shell option only ever comes into action when you try to explicitly expand a variable which is not set. This is happening in `var="${var}something"`, but not in `var+=something`.

The statement `var+=something` contains no mentioning of `$var`, so there's no explicit expansion of any unset variable.

In my mind it's ok that this is the way it is in `bash`, for two reasons:

1. I think about `nounset` to refer to explicit expansions of variables.
2. The `+=` operator is an extension to the POSIX standard, so a POSIX shell option need not affect it.

If you need to check whether `var` is defined before appending a value to it, use something like

```bash
if [[ -v var ]]; then
    var+=something
else
    echo 'Unset variable var' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

(i.e. test with the built-in `-v` test), or, if you rely on `nounset` to catch actual uses of unset variables, use the `var=${var}something` syntax.